# List Weeks of Year in a Month in PHP

Tags: php, php-carbon

The scenario I have here is that, I need to select a **Year** and **Month**. And I need to show the **Weeks** in that currently selected **Month**. Let me explain it here ...

`2017 -> Oct -> Week N` 
( this should be the Week of year . E.x this week is `#40 for 2017`.) So I need to list number of weeks that lies in Oct for this year.

Thank you.

Comment: In moth week number also differ date wise. So explain  according to which date you need week number?

Comment: I need to list the WeekOfYear that is containing in the selected month. Let's say Oct has 5 weeks for this year and the beginning week is Week#40. I need to display Week#40,Week#41,Week#42,Week#43,Week#44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code: Get first day and last day of month, count week numbers and loop over it

```
$year = "2017";
$month = "10";
$day = "01";
$first_date = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
$last_date = date("Y-m-t",strtotime($first_date));
$first_week = date("W",strtotime($first_date));
$last_week = date("W",strtotime($last_date));
for($i=$first_week;$i<=$last_week;$i++)
{
    echo "Week #".$i.", ";
}
```

Note that October has total 6 weeks. 1st date on Sunday last on Tuesday

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/YviJo)

Answer (score 1):

Considered Michel's solution [How to get year-sensitive calendar week ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20843717/8197560) to avoid excess week from previous december to current january.

```
function getWeekNo( $date ) {

    $t = strtotime($date) ;
    $w=(int)date('W', $t);
    $m=(int)date('n', $t);
    $w=($w==1?($m==12?53:1):($w>=51?($m==1?0:$w):$w));

    return $w ;
}

$month = '10-2017' ;
$firstDay = '01-' . $month ;
$lastDay  = Date('t-m-Y', strtotime($firstDay)) ;

$firstWeek = getWeekNo($firstDay) ;
$lastWeek = getWeekNo($lastDay) ;
for( $i = $firstWeek; $i <= $lastWeek; $i++ ) {
    //echo "Week $i <br/>";
    echo "Week " . ($i + 1) . "<br/>"; //if you want to start january 1st as Week 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Desai's answer, I tried this on Carbon PHP ( on Laravel 5.5 ). I'm posting my answer in case anyone is looking for this.

```
        $month = 10;
        $year = 2017;

        $date = \Carbon\Carbon::create($year,$month);

        $startOfMonth = $date->startOfMonth();
        $endOfMonth = $date->copy()->endOfMonth();

        $startWeek = $startOfMonth->format('W');
        $endWeek = $endOfMonth->copy()->format('W');

        for( $i = $startWeek; $i <= $endWeek; $i++ )
        {
           echo "Week #" . $i;
        }
```

Thank you all for your answers. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

According to carbon documentation at [CarbonDocs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2012-9-5 23:26:11.123789');
var_dump($dt->weekOfYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reply yet to the first comment, but the above solution is not working correctly if the last day of month have in first week of new year (test case: 2019-12-01).

I made a quick fix (based on original code):

```
// Input date format: YYYY-mm-dd    
function getMonthWeekNumbers( $first_date )
{
    $last_date = date( "Y-m-t",strtotime( $first_date ) );
    $first_week = date( "W",strtotime( $first_date ) );
    $last_week = date( "W",strtotime( $last_date ) );

    // If last day of month have on first week on next year, subtract a week from the date
    if( $last_week == '01' )
    {
        $last_week = date( "W",( strtotime( $last_date )-604800 ) );
    }

    for( $i=$first_week; $i <= $last_week; $i++ )
    {
        echo "Week #".$i.", ";
    }
}
```

It working fine with any input dates.

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hSemf)